# Normalize data frame by levels

Tags: r, excel

Good evening,

I am still new to R, so sorry in advance if this question seems obvious to you. 
I am currently working on a drug screening protocol and I created .csv table in Excel with the output of my analysis. I imported it as data frame as `raw.data` into R with the following structure:

```
| Sample        | Group | Parameter Drug 1 | Parameter Drug 2 | Time Parameter Drug 1 (ms) |
|---------------|-------|------------------|------------------|----------------------------|
| Heart_Sample1 | Heart | 2.4              | 9.0              | 1.5                        |
| Heart_Sample1 | Heart | 2.29             | 22.2             | 3.4                        |
| Heart_Sample1 | Heart | 3.4              | 3.5              | 4.5                        |
| Heart_Sample1 | Heart | 5.2              | 8.4              | 6.5                        |
| Heart_Sample1 | Heart | 2.3              | 34.1             | 7.8                        |
| ...           | Organ | value            | value            | time                       |
| Heart_Sample2 | Heart | 10.4             | 10.2             | 1.5                        |
| Heart_Sample2 | Heart | 8.4              | 2.45             | 3.6                        |
| ...           | Organ | value            | value            | time                       |
| Liver_Sample1 | Liver | 13.4             | 44.5             | 2.8                        |
| ...           | Organ | 2.3              | value            | time                       |
```

Parameter indicates the value of a certain parameter I am experimentally measuring (e.g. neuronal spikes). Time of Parameter indicates the time of the recording at which the spikes occur.

I transformed `raw.data` into `mod.data` with `gather` with the following formula:

```
  mod.data <- gather(raw.data, `Parameter Drug 1`, `Parameter Drug 2`, `Parameter Drug 3`, key = "Drug", value = "value")




| Sample        | Group | Time Parameter Drug 1 (ms) | Drug            | value |
|---------------|-------|----------------------------|-----------------|-------|
| Heart_Sample1 | Heart |                            | Baseline        |       |
| Heart_Sample1 | Heart |                            | Baseline        |       |
| Heart_Sample1 | Heart |                            | Concentration 1 |       |
| Heart_Sample1 | Heart |                            | Concentration 1 |       |
| Heart_Sample1 | Heart |                            | Concentration 2 |       |
```

Then I generated the plots, separated by Sample and , in order to have a clear overview of what is happening to the parameter, over time, in all the samples. The results is a huge plot array, with ~200 plots.

Since different organs have different values, and also within the same organ I can find very different values, the scales have to be matched within each Sample to clearly understand what is going in the sample.

I then tried to normalize with the following function:

```
    normalize <- function(x){
  (x - min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))
  }
```

Where x is my parameter of interest. Unfortunately, it takes as `min` and `max` the respective `min` and `max` of the whole Parameter, regardless of the Sample and the Group. I also try to subset, but it would mean to create a single subset for each Sample and then merge them together in a figure. I also try with `group_by(Sample, Group)`, as described in the RStudio cheatsheet, but I was not able to apply the normalize function to the generated data frame.

**tl;dr My question is: how can I normalize, from 0 to 1, within each Sample, my values?**

Thank you in advance for the answers.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another approach using `dplyr` and your `normalize` function. I had no issues applying it to the toy data I created.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(Sample = sample(c("Sample1", "Sample2"), 20, replace = T),
                 Group = sample(c("Heart", "Liver"), 20, replace = T),
                 Time = sample(100:500, 20),
                 Value = sample(1000:5000, 20))

normalize <- function(x){
  (x - min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))
} 

df %>%
  group_by(Sample, Group) %>%
  mutate(Time_std = normalize(Time),
         Value_std = normalize(Value)) %>%
  arrange(Sample, Group, Time_std)

  #  Sample  Group  Time Value   Time_std  Value_std
  # Sample1  Heart   317  2895 0.00000000 0.47500000
  # Sample1  Heart   389  3441 0.57600000 1.00000000
  # Sample1  Heart   436  2755 0.95200000 0.34038462
  # Sample1  Heart   442  2401 1.00000000 0.00000000
  # Sample1  Liver   149  2513 0.00000000 0.00000000
  # Sample1  Liver   154  2792 0.01428571 0.24303136
  # Sample1  Liver   157  3661 0.02285714 1.00000000
  # Sample1  Liver   272  3510 0.35142857 0.86846690
  # Sample1  Liver   499  2535 1.00000000 0.01916376
  # Sample2  Heart   179  1877 0.00000000 0.15939905
  # Sample2  Heart   204  4171 0.39062500 1.00000000
  # Sample2  Heart   243  1442 1.00000000 0.00000000
  # Sample2  Liver   117  4011 0.00000000 0.92470805
  # Sample2  Liver   147  1002 0.10238908 0.00000000
  # Sample2  Liver   160  4256 0.14675768 1.00000000
  # Sample2  Liver   192  4236 0.25597270 0.99385372
  # Sample2  Liver   246  2096 0.44027304 0.33620160
  # Sample2  Liver   265  1379 0.50511945 0.11585741
  # Sample2  Liver   283  4244 0.56655290 0.99631223
  # Sample2  Liver   410  3832 1.00000000 0.86969883
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I run it I obtain a value of 1 for Sample1, and a value of 0 for Sample2, which is not correct unfortunately. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36889/Screen%20Shot%202017-03-28%20at%2022.52.31.png

Comment: I edited my answer to make it reproducible with the `set.seed` and easier to read the output with the `arrange`. You'll always have a value of 0 and 1 in each group corresponding to the min/max values in that group, so I'm afraid I'm not quite understanding what you mean

Comment: Thank you, sorry, as a novice I have a few difficulties. In you example, what I find not correct is the fact that everything is on the same 0-1 normalisation (i.e. one 0 and one 1 for the whole column). I would like to have four 0 and four 1 (with values in between), each one corresponding to each Sample.

Comment: In my example, the `Time_std` column has four 0 values and four 1 values, corresponding to each Sample/Group combination. Is this not what you're going for?

Comment: I am obtaining the correct output only if I run with R (v 3.3.3 Mac), but not with RStudio (v 1.0.136 Mac). Frankly unexpected, but thank you for the answer!
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36889/Screen%20Shot%202017-03-28%20at%2023.14.56.png

Comment: Interesting. I think this goes way beyond what I understand, but perhaps your RStudio session isn't pointing to the most updated R version on your system. I'm running v 3.3.2 on Windows through RStudio, for what that's worth

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` you could go about this using the following approach.

Toy example:

```
library(data.table)
normalize <- function(x){
  (x - min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))
} 

df <- data.table(group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), measure = c(10, 20, 0, 2, 1, 1, 10))
df[, measure_normalized := normalize(measure), by = group]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I do have problems with this method since normalising for Group includes also the other drug concentrations performed on the same group, so the baseline will be close to 0 and the highest concentration close to 1, while what I was looking for is a normalisation within each dose of each sample of each group.